# SendKeys() permission denied error in Visual Basic

Tags: vb6, sendkeys

I am trying to use the `SendKeys()` command to another window with my VB6 app.

What I wanted is to click a button, and then have 10 seconds to go to the other window before the app sends some keys to that window. I got everything sorted but for some reason when I call something like this:

```
SendKeys ("A")
```

I get this error:

```
Run-time error '70':

Permission denied
```

Does anyone know a way around this? Thanks.

Comment: If you're on Vista this might be caused by user-account control (UAC).  You can workaround by turning off UAC.

Answer (score 24):

**For Windows 7:**
Change the UAC settings to never notify.

**For Windows 8 and 10:**
Add this method to any module:

```
Public Sub Sendkeys(text as variant, Optional wait As Boolean = False)
   Dim WshShell As Object
   Set WshShell = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
   WshShell.Sendkeys cstr(text), wait
   Set WshShell = Nothing
End Sub
```

It's worked fine for me in windows 10.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me!

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at what Karl Peterson worked up as a fix for this under Vista:

[SendInput](http://vb.mvps.org/samples/SendInput/)

Answer (score 6):

Replacement for VB6 SendKeys is WScript.Shell SendKeys, like this:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "1{+}"
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83(v=vs.84).aspx) for help.

Answer (score 6):

In a public Module add:

```
Public Sub Sendkeys(text$, Optional wait As Boolean = False)
    Dim WshShell As Object
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
    WshShell.Sendkeys text, wait
    Set WshShell = Nothing
End Sub
```

This will "overwrite" SendKeys Function

Answer (score 4):

On Windows 7:

- Open the Control Panel
- Change user account control setting
- Change to NEVER NOTIFY
- Restart the computer

Answer (score 2):

Delete "msvbvm60.dll" File From The Application

Follow The Following Step

> 1. Right Click On The Application .Exe File And Click On Property
> 2. Click On Compatibility Tab
> 3. Click On Run This Program in Compatibility  Mode And Chose Windows
>      Xp SP2 From It.
> 4. Click On Run This Program As Administrator
> 5. Click On Apply Than Ok.
> 6. Delete The  "msvbvm60.dll" From The Application Folder.

All Done, Now Your Application Start Running Without Any Error Like Access Denied

Answer (score 1):

the problem is about vb6 IDE and windows desktop context menu and you will do as described in here :

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?747425-SendKeys-and-Windows-8

and main reference is here :

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?745925-RESOLVED-How-to-trigger-the-desktop-context-menu

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in Module

```
Public Sub SendKeyTab(CForm As Form)
On Error Resume Next
Dim G As Single
For G = 0 To CForm .Controls.Count - 1
    If CForm .Controls(G).TabIndex = CForm .ActiveControl.TabIndex + 1 Then CForm .Controls(G).SetFocus
Next
End Sub
```

On Each Form Level

```
If KeyCode
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this API:

```
Public Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
```

and

```
keybd_event keycode, 0, 0, 0  'KEY DOWN
keybd_event keycode, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0 'KEY UP
```

when key code is 32 for space, 35 for keyend, 8 for vbKeyBack, etc.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try to provide more explanation to your answers along with better formatting. See [How to answer page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for help in improving your answer.