# Why is my on-screen keyboard numlock being activated during this code?

Tags: excel, vba

I have added this code to my macro to automatically interact with an existing IE window. It works perfectly and does what I am trying to accomplish, but for some reason every time I run this code it activates my on-screen keyboard num lock, which disables the "-" key on the top right on my num pad, and the only way to get that key working again is to open my on-screen keyboard and click num lock. Any help fixing this would be great.

```
If Cells(19, "AB").Value = False And Cells(20, "AB").Value = False And Cells(21, "AB").Value = False Then

Dim ie As Object
Dim SubjectLine As String
Dim Distro As String
Dim Body As String

Dim GetIE As Object
For Each GetIE In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows() 'Loop to find
If (Not GetIE Is Nothing) And GetIE.Name = "Internet Explorer" Then Exit For 'Found!
Next GetIE
GetIE.Visible = True 'Make IE window visible
Set ie = GetIE

Dim HWNDSrc As Long
HWNDSrc = ie.HWND
SetForegroundWindow HWNDSrc

Dim sIEURL As String
sIEURL = ie.LocationURL

'Checks the URL so it can decide which set of code to run
If InStr(sIEURL, "mail.CompanyName.com") > 0 Then

'*********************************THIS SET IS FOR OLD VERSION OF WEBMAIL**********************************************

' Copies the distrobution list. IF you do not copy/paste it, it will not recognize different email addresses.
'These code change the distro line
Sheets("Setup").Range("F8").Copy
Sheets("Main Email Work Area").Select
SetForegroundWindow HWNDSrc

Set tags = ie.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
tags(0).Click
tags(0).Focus
Application.SendKeys ("^v"), True
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")



'This code sets the subject line
Sheets("Main Email Work Area").Select
Range(Cells(7, "J"), Cells(7, "M")).Select
Selection.Copy

SetForegroundWindow HWNDSrc
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
tags(3).Click
tags(3).Focus
Application.SendKeys ("^v"), True
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")




'This code sets the email body
Sheets("Main Email Work Area").Select
emailBodyCopy = 120
While Cells(emailBodyCopy, "J").Value = ""
       emailBodyCopy = emailBodyCopy - 1
Wend
Range(Cells(emailBodyCopy, "J"), Cells(13, "L")).Select
Selection.Copy

SetForegroundWindow HWNDSrc

Set bodyarea = ie.Document.GetElementsByClassName("allowTextSelection _mcp_32 customScrollBar ms-bg-color-white ms-font-color-black owa-font-compose")
bodyarea(0).Click
bodyarea(0).Focus
Application.SendKeys ("^v"), True
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")


'Tries to click the attach button
Set attach = ie.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")
For Each Button In attach
If Button.Title = "Attach" Then
Button.Click
Exit For
End If
Next

Set ie = Nothing

Else

'*********************************THIS SET IS FOR OFFICE365 VERSION OF WEBMAIL**********************************************
' Copies the distrobution list. IF you do not copy/paste it, it will not recognize different email addresses.
Sheets("Setup").Range("F8").Copy
Sheets("Main Email Work Area").Select

SetForegroundWindow HWNDSrc

'These code change the distro line
Set tags = ie.Document.GetElementsByTagName("Input")
tags(3).Click
tags(3).Focus
Application.SendKeys ("^v"), True
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")


'This code sets the subject line
Sheets("Main Email Work Area").Select
Range(Cells(7, "J"), Cells(7, "M")).Select
Selection.Copy

SetForegroundWindow HWNDSrc

tags(5).Click
tags(5).Focus
Application.Wait (Now + 0.000005)
Application.SendKeys ("^v"), True
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")


'This code sets the email body
Sheets("Main Email Work Area").Select
emailBodyCopy = 120
While Cells(emailBodyCopy, "J").Value = ""
       emailBodyCopy = emailBodyCopy - 1
Wend
Range(Cells(emailBodyCopy, "J"), Cells(13, "L")).Select
Selection.Copy

SetForegroundWindow HWNDSrc

Set Tag = ie.Document.GetElementsByClassName("_4utP_vaqQ3UQZH0GEBVQe B1QSRkzQCtvCtutReyNZ _17ghdPL1NLKYjRvmoJgpoK _2s9KmFMlfdGElivl0o-GZb")
Tag(0).Click
Tag(0).Focus
Application.SendKeys ("^v"), True


' This finds the attach button and clicks it
Set attach = ie.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")
For Each Button In attach
If Button.Name = "Attach" Then
Button.Click
Exit For
End If
Next

'This finds the "Browse" button inside the attach dropdown and clicks it.
Set attach = ie.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")
For Each Button In attach
If Button.Name = "Browse this computer" Then
Button.Click
Exit For
End If
Next


Set ie = Nothing

End If

'Ends the IF for the auto copy/paste
End If
```

This is part of a much larger macro that is ran. I am currently using Office365 so it is running the portion of the code that is for Office 365 only, but I wanted to put the entire code that was added that is causing this issue, just in case. With this section being added, it causes the num lock issue, without this section, it does not cause the issue, so it has to be something in this.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a known issue when using SendKeys with VBA.

Comment: @TimWilliams Is there any fix or way around it? Anything I can add at the end of my code to essentially turn off num lock on my on screen keyboard?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42440776/turning-numlock-on-at-the-end-of-a-macro-run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to add

```
Sendkeys "{NUMLOCK}", True
```

To the end of my code right before the last End If and it seemed to have fixed the problem.

Thanks to help from @timWilliams