# Send multimedia keys using VB6

Tags: vb6

I know that pause/play key(from keyboard)'s keyCode is 179, but how can I programically press those multimedia keys from VB6? There are some questions about it but they're for C#/C++/VB.Net

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Chr function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/chr-function) to convert your keycode to a string that [SendKeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/sendkeys-statement) can use:

```
SendKeys Chr(179)
```

You might run into a [Permission Denied error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307738/sendkeys-permission-denied-error-in-visual-basic) next, which you can work around by using a WScript.Shell object by using this subroutine:

```
Private Sub SendKeysViaWshShell(p_iKeyCode As Integer, Optional p_fWait As Boolean = False)
   Dim objWshShell As Object
   Set objWshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   objWshShell.SendKeys Chr(p_iKeyCode), p_fWait
   Set objWshShell = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried Chr(179( with the following code but the pressed keyCode was 16.
```
Private Sub Form_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    MsgBox KeyCode
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    SendKeys Chr(179)
End Sub
```

Comment: `Form_KeyDown` event should not occur when `SendKeys` is used. I have tried `SendKeysViaWshShell 179` here and it starts/stop my media player. Please update your question with your latest code so we can see what you are doing.

Comment: I used your SendKeysViaWshShell function, but the KeyDown event occured, and the KeyCode was always 144. Note that I use Windows XP.

Comment: Please update your question with your latest code so we can see what you are doing.